# SQL Server View to Return Consecutive rows with a Specific Value

Tags: sql, view

Consider this data from TestTable:

[image]

I need a view that will provide that most recent beginning StatusDate where IsAssist is true.  For example, the most recent StatusDate where IsAssist is true is 2014-05-25.  Since the immediately previous records are also IsAssist = true, I need to include those in the calculation.  So the beginning of the "IsAssist Block" is 2014-05-22.  This is the date I need.

How can I write a view that will provide this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - I managed to figure this out with the help of JL Peyret's response.  I had to reverse the parameters for the between statement (when did MS do this?  Has it always been this way?).

What it does is determine the low date by getting the StatusDate where IsAssist = 0 and is less than the max StatusDate where IsAssist = 1.  The high date is simply the max StatusDate where IsAssist = 1.

Check between these dates where IsAssist = 1 and there you have it, the most recent block of records where IsAssist = 1.

I realize this isn't quite finished yet.  I have to cover for the possibility that the low date calculation might fail because there aren't any records where IsAssist = 0.  Details...

JL was very close and deserves credit for getting me on the right path.  Thanks!

```
select * 
from TestTablewhere StatusDate 
between
/* the low date */
(select max(StatusDate)
from TestTable
Where IsAssist = 0
and StatusDate < (select max(StatusDate) from TestTable s where IsAssist = 1))
and
/* the high date */
(select max(StatusDate) from TestTable s where IsAssist = 1)
and IsAssist = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

this should give you a good start

```
  Select s.tableid, s.StatusDate, e,TableId, e.StatusDate
  from testable s -- for start
      left join testable e -- for end
          on e.statusdate = 
               (Select Min(StatusDate)
                From TestTable
                Where StatusDate > s.StatusDate
                    and isAssist = 1
                    and Not exists
                        (Select * From testable
                         Where StatusDate Betweens.StatusDate and e.StatusDate
                             and isAssist = 0))
  Where s.IsAssist = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, Charles.  This does give me some ideas for reporting, which is down the road a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from TestTable
where StatusDate 
between

/* the low date */

(
select min(StatusDate)
from TestTable s3

/* grab oldest entry which is <= than the high date*/



where StatusDate <= (select max(StatusDate) from TestTable s where IsAssist = 1)
and IsAssist = 1

/* but has no later isAssist = 0 rows */
and not exists 
(select 1
from TestTable s4
where s4.StatusDate > s3.StatusDate
and IsAssist = 0
)
)
```

and     /* the high date */
    (select max(StatusDate) from TestTable s
    where IsAssist = 1
    )
    and

Comment: Thanks, JL.  This is very close to what I need.  You got me started on a query that will work.  BTW - This particular query will never return the expected results because the max date is the first parameter in the between statement.  Between must have the low date first, then the high date.  My answer, which is very close to what you provided here, is posted below.

Comment: Yes, I have changed that now.  I was gonna SQLFiddle it, but that site kept on not wanting to build the schema, though it is back to normal now.  I would advise you to specifically test boundary conditions and test scenarios, things like no isAssist =1 existing at all or no earlier rows that match your criteria.  Just put in a few dummy rows now and check behavior, query adjustment for this kinda stuff is usually trivial, but you need to be aware of the problem.